# Laravel API: RegisterController set a default value on creating an User not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

I started working on a Laravel API project.
I added a column to the users table to refer to the account id.
After updating the Model with the needed fillable key, the column value
stays empty after registring an user. I dont actually know where the problem is.

Also the return is not containing the new column.

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'account_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $table = 'api_users';
}
```

**Register Controller: create function**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'account_id' => time(),
    ]);
}
```

**Database Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('api_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('account_id', 60)->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_users');
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you replace `User::create` with `User::forceCreate`? Are you using the correct User import in your controller? Did you modified and re-run your migrations? Could you post these as well?

Comment: Its creating the data entry. But the column is just staying empty. Its the only User import, so it must be correct. I modified the migrations, but is there an another command for remigrating ? Using 'artisan migrate' just prints: nothing to migrate

Comment: If you don't mind losing the data you have in your tables you can do: `php artisan migrate:fresh` (drop all tables and migrate) or `php artisan migrate:refresh` (rollback and rerun migrations)

Comment: Regarding the user import was just making sure you imported the `App\User` model and maybe not `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` as a mistake

Comment: @mdexp i added the migration now. I think a migrate wouldnt work at all, because the column definition and migration was added to a fresh project before migrating it

Comment: As Im saying the User Creation works. Its passing the data fine except my custom created column in the table. This field stays empty without a reason

Comment: I found out that the register controller is somehow not even used.. When I remove the class, the user is still getting created - no errors. So where is the actual function of creating the User in the Model ?

Comment: The `create` method is called by the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait, but it's strange that if you remove that controller the code still works. Can you provide the ouput of `php artisan route:list`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the foreign account_id reference you are using is not valid.

Comment: its basically just the new column i have added before migrating the users table Edit: // Or do you mean the name itself i have chosen is not valid ?

Comment: Could you give more information about the error?  mayb using try and catch?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero there is no error given. The column just stays empty so I dont know where to search for..

Comment: Could you paste the datatable definition?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero its a string based field: varchar(60): Default value => empty | Allow Null: true

Comment: time() is an integer. Maybe is that. Please try with casting  'account_id' => (string) time(), or set your column as integer.

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero I found out that the register controller is somehow not even used.. When I remove the class, the user is still getting created - no errors. So where is the actual function of creating the User in the Model ?

Comment: Creating function is in the parent class so, in Model. Model has a lots of traits you can investigate.